# Multiple UI threads for page (speed up slow individual controls)

Tags: c#, multithreading, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

I am currently writing a kiosk style app in UWP (windows IoT Core), for use on embedded devices (e.g. pi3, etc.).

The device has several sensors, which are being output in real time into various graphs/charts in a single screen in the app, but I'm running into performance problems. The sensors are being read in separate threads (using Task.Run() => {}), but after analysis, this doesn't seem to cost that much cpu time at all.
It seems that updating the graphs take too much time and this isnt being distributed over the cores, since there is only a single UI thread. CPU usage doesnt get past 25%, the UI responsiveness just gets slow.

I tried several optimizations (e.g. reducing the amount of data points, etc.), which helps, but its not enough. Maybe there are faster chart components out there (currently using Telerik uwp component), but I was looking for another approach.

**So summary of my question:** Is there any way to have the charts each render in separate UI threads (and thus be distributed over the other cores somewhat)?

[UPDATE some time later]
Seems like the new win IoT release is a bit faster, as well as the newer chart component.

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing how your application is written, but one possibility could be that the UI is being updated too often by all these other background threads? What about the possibility of queuing up the updates, and updating the UI on a scheduled basis, like every .1 or .5 seconds? If there's a lot going on on your UI thread, you might be suffering too many context switches.

Comment: I have tried doing the updates from the different threads themselves and using your approach. Doesn't seem to make much difference in use so far, also with tweaking of Dispatcher.Runasync priority settings. And I have to add more charts even.

Comment: Are your charts being completely redrawn every time, or only pieces of it?

Comment: Well, every data point changes for every loop, so I refresh the whole bound datacontext, yes. Cant really find a way around this so far.

Comment: Can you show your code sample?

Comment: Have you considered implementing custom charts with GPU acceleration? That would solve all your problems, if you find relevant examples.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no directx GPU support for the PI3 on iot as far as I know, so hence the intense CPU usage. Would need to switch hardware platform, but that would increase unit price.

Answer (score 0):

Can't speak strictly for UWP but from my experience of WPF having multiple UI threads is a hassle which you should avoid if at all possible (not to speak of the limitations they introduce).

When dealing with your sensor data what kind of polling rate are you looking at? Many sensors have a data rate which far outstrips what is useful to display to the user, would it be possible to have your worker thread compute an averaged value for a larger time frame and populate your graph with that? I doubt your users will see much of a benefit from updating them more than 20 times a second.

Comment: The sensors poll only like every 200-500ms. Even with faster polling rates, the sensors themselves hardly take up any cpu time. Its the 4+ charts that redraw every 500ms that gulp up all the CPU time on the UI thread. I could slow down the rate, but it takes a bit away from the experience. And there are more charts coming. If I could smear these out across the other CPU cores, which are currently doing nothing, this would help.

Comment: What control are you using for your charts? Are you able to post any code of you updating the underlying data?

Comment: Im using this Telerik chart control. http://docs.telerik.com/windows-universal/controls/radchart/getting-started. Basically it is an array with 25 fresh sensor values that I assign to the DataContext property (like in the example of that page) from the background thread every 500ms, using Dispatcher.RunAsync. Pretty standard.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the Graphs using Tasks too, just remember to use a dispatcher inside them, because changing UI from non UI threads is illegal.

For more info check this out:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/keep-the-ui-thread-responsive

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher